# SQL Create view with specific values from one-to-many relation

Tags: sql, sql-server

Having the following table structure in MSSQL to represent an Employee and the EmployeeData table is used to enable "dynamic" extension of the Employee model to keep different types of data depending on the Employee.

```
table : Employee
+-------+-----------+------------------+-------------------+
|   Id  | FirstName | EmploymentNumber |       Phone       |
+-------+-----------+------------------+-------------------+
|   1   |   John    |            123   |   214-444-1234    |
|   2   |   Mary    |            456   |   555-111-1234    |
|   3   |   Jeff    |            345   |   214-222-1234    |
|   4   |   Bill    |            567   |   817-333-1234    |
|   5   |   Bob     |            678   |   214-555-1234    |
+-------+-----------+------------------+-------------------+

table : EmployeeData
+-------+------------+-----+-------------+--------------+------------+---------+
| id | EmployeeId | DataId | StringValue | BooleanValue |  FromDate  | ToDate  |
+----+------------+--------+-------------+--------------+------------+---------+
|  1 |      1     |    1   | Developer   |     NULL     | NULL       | NULL    |
|  2 |      1     |    2   | Team 1      |     NULL     | 20230101   | 20230131|
|  3 |      1     |    2   | Team 2      |     NULL     | 20230201   | NULL    |
|  4 |      2     |    1   | Tester      |     NULL     | NULL       | NULL    |
|  5 |      2     |    3   | NULL        |     1        | 20230101   | NULL    |
+----+------------+--------+-------------+--------------+------------+---------+
table : Data
+-------+------------+----------+
| id |    Name   |   Type       |
+----+-----------+--------------+
|  1 | Title     | StringValue  |
|  2 | Team      | StringValue  |
|  3 | IsManager | BooleanValue |
+----+------------+--------+----+
```

The values in the EmployeeData have a nullable FromDate and ToDate to represent a specific period where the value was "active", but these values can be null in all combinations, i.e. both can be null for a value that never "expires", FromDate or ToDate can be null if there are no start or no current end to the value.

The Data table is used to Name the field but also point to which type field (GuidValue, StringValue etc) which the Data stores the value in i.e. Name:Salary/Type:DecimalValue, Name:Title/Type:StringValue

Based on this structure I want to create Views in SQL that could represent different aspects of employees depending on the usecase.

Like this:

```
+-----------+------------------+-----------+--------+-----------+
| FirstName | EmploymentNumber |   Title   |  Team  | IsManager |
+-----------+------------------+-----------+--------------------+
|   John    |       123        | Developer | Team 2 |    0      |
|   Mary    |       456        | Tester    | Team 3 |    1      |
+-------+----------------------+-----------+--------------------+
```

How do I create these Views in the most efficient way selecting the, in most cases, latest value from EmployeeData alongside some of the Employee table data?

In the simplest form I would not need to use the Data table since I can set the specific valuecolumn to read from but is there a way to use the Type value in the Data table to select the value from that named column in the EmployeeData table?

What I have so far working is this:

```
SELECT e.FirstName, e.EmploymentNumber,
(
  SELECT TOP (1) StringValue 
  FROM [EmployeeData] 
  WHERE EmployeeId = e.Id 
    AND DataId = 1 
    AND (GETDATE() BETWEEN ISNULL(FromDate, DATEADD(DD, - 1, 
    GETDATE()))
    AND ISNULL(ToDate, DATEADD(DD, 1, GETDATE())))
    AND CompanyId = 2
 ) [Title],
(
  SELECT TOP (1) StringValue 
  FROM [EmployeeData] 
  WHERE EmployeeId = e.Id 
    AND DataId = 2 
    AND (GETDATE() BETWEEN ISNULL(FromDate, DATEADD(DD, - 1, 
    GETDATE()))
    AND ISNULL(ToDate, DATEADD(DD, 1, GETDATE())))
    AND CompanyId = 2
 ) [Team]

  FROM [Employee] e
  WHERE e.CompanyId = 2
```

But it feels like there could be better ways perhaps, not so verbal?

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results to illustrate the problem you are trying to solve... its not clear to me as stated.

Comment: If you have some interesting set of values, you could do a pivot on them and create each value as a view column. It will be hardcoded a bit but probably a bit better than your current solution. Or do the pivot when fetching data, so your view just contains "current" values. Either way, perhaps you should take a look at temporal tables which handles the "dated" parts of your logi